# Generating library that uses symbols from an application

Tags: c++, qt, linker, mingw

I have an application built with QtCreator (QT5.13) that consists of an application MyApp and let's say one dynamic library MyLib.
This dynamic library also calls functions defined in the application.

1) With the correct INCLUDEPATH and the header files, my project compiles and executes on windows platform using MSVC.

2) I ported the project on unix Ubuntu (QT5.13) also with success but with minor modification on the .PRO basically adding "-r dynamic" and removing the direct reference "**LIBS += $$PWD/lib/MyApp.lib**"

3) Now I went to compile my project on windows platform wit Mingw (mingw730_64).
The App compiles and the executable file is generated. But i get error with the linker of MyLib. For example :

> error : undefined reference to  `__imp__ZN13FBSFBaseModelC2Ev'

and for all symbols present in the MyApp that are called by MyLib.

I obviously don't understand the linkage process with the platforms and how compiler manages to resolve symbols statically or dynamically.
Thanks for the help

On Windows and Mingw I tried without 
    **GCC:QMAKE_LFLAGS    +=    -r dynamic**
get the undefined references.

I tried with "**GCC:QMAKE_LFLAGS += -r dynamic**" but seem not recognized by winGW

MyApp.PRO  that works for windows / MVSC:

```
    TARGET    =    MyApp
    TEMPLATE    =    app
    LIBS    +=    -L$$PWD/lib    -lOtherLib
    GCC:QMAKE_LFLAGS += -r dynamic
```

MyLib.PRO for linux and GCC that works :

```
    TARGET    =    MyLib
    TEMPLATE    =    lib
    WIN32:LIBS    +=    $$PWD/lib/MyApp.lib
```

Comment: Why do you want to use symbols from the app in the library? That's basically all backwards. If you want to use plain C++, then library should provide interface class, which is extended by the app and passed as pointer to the library to be used. If you want to use Qt meta object system, then library should use that to access relevant features of the objects passed to the library by the app. But library should not directly try to access symbols of the app. It's not really a library if it does...

Comment: Anyway, try using static library, and this problem should go away (because static library is just a bunch of .o files packed together).

Comment: Thanks Hyde for your 2 comments. I am not the designer of the project which much more bigger then the example that I tired to explain. The app is not just a main bu it also provide a base class that the MyLib inherit for one of its own class.

Comment: The idea is also to understand how compilers and OS manage the link of shared library. further more the project compile and run on MSVC windows and GCC Linux.  but has a problem with mingw on windows

Comment: " it also provide a base class that the MyLib inherit for one of its own class" - move that base class to the lib then? With cyclic dependencies, why bother and have separate app and lib at all?

Comment: The class definition, the .h file that is, is it part of the library or part of the app? That is, does the library just expect definition of methods (and static data?) from the app code? Or does the library actually include .h file from the app code base?

Comment: Anyway, this sounds like case of *composition over inheritance*. Lib should not subclass this class with implementation coming from elsewhere. Class in lib should take instance of class as (constructor) parameter to initialize a member variable (value, reference, pointer or smart pointer depending on other design details). AKA dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, having a library requiring symbols from the exe file is backward.

Anyway. On Linux it works with `-rdynamics` because Linux's ELF format can support undefined symbols.

On Windows, you **must** provide tips to the linker for where to find the symbols. So you will never have an `-rdynamics` option. What you do is provide a `.lib` file that describes which symbols will be available in the exe file.

That's why `WIN32:LIBS    +=    $$PWD/lib/MyApp.lib` makes it work for MSVC.

However, MinGW does not recognize `.lib` files, but instead uses `.a` files.
So you need to replace `$$PWD/lib/MyApp.lib` with `$$PWD/lib/MyApp.a`.

Note that if you do not have a `MyApp.a` generated when you compile `MyApp.exe`, than can means 2 things:

1. You need to add `-Wl,--out-implib=MyApp.a` to the link command of your exe.
2. You need to mark exported symbols with `__declspec(dllexport)` in your app code.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for your explanations.  the "dllexport" where already in the code but I cant add what the option you provided me for the link command.  I am using QtCreator and I tried in pro file : 
TARGET      = MyApp
TEMPLATE    = app
CONFIG      += qtquickcompiler
QT          += core qml quick xml widgets
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -WlQMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl ;
But Wl is not recognized so how can I  change the .pro to make the compiler generate  .a lib for my executable ?

Comment: Use `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--out-implib=MyApp.a`

Comment: Thanks all of you and specially Benjamin T. I will consider a refactoring later for the design app/lib that all of you suggested

Comment: @papitou34 If the answer has solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. You can also upvote useful comments.

Comment: Benjamin it seems that new users can't upvote :"Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." How do I mark the issue solved ?

Comment: @papitou34 Click on the check mark on the left of the answer.